# Copying a ADODB recordset into a Table without Looping

Tags: adodb

Can someone please provide sample code for the following

I need to copy data from SQL Server database to a Microsoft Access database. I am using VBA.

I have an Access table "Loadtime". Required data is in a recordset ObjRecSQL. Same columns, Data types match etc. I populated ObjrecSQL from tables in a SQL Server database based on some conditions. I need to get all the data in ObjrecSQL updated to Loadtime without looping. Looks like UpdateBatch does it. But how do i copy from ObjrecSQL to a new recordset and indicate that it needs to update Loadtime.